# error message: package or namespace load failed for ""

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm encountering a problem in loading the package ggpubr. This is new and I could load the package a few days ago...

Here is the message I get:

```
 `Erreur : package or namespace load failed for ‘ggpubr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 impossible de charger l'objet partagé '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
De plus : Warning message:
le package ‘ggpubr’ a été compilé avec la version R 4.0.2`
```

Any clue about the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ggpubr has a recursive dependency on Rcpp. See

```
packrat:::recursivePackageDependencies("ggpubr",lib.loc = .libPaths()[1])
```

One possible solution that might work is to uninstall ggpubr, then install Rcpp with dependencies, then install ggubr with dependencies:

```
remove.packages("ggpubr")
install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("ggpubr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Unfortunately, the suggested answer did not work...
Any other idea??

Comment: Can you successfully load the Rcpp package?


    library(Rcpp)

Comment: indeed I can't 
receiving the same kind of error 
''Erreur : package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcpp’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...): etc... ""